# Is there any method to for sensor fusion of accelerometer ,gyroscope and barrometer?

Tags: height, accelerometer, gyroscope, kalman-filter, sensor-fusion

I want sensor fusion for accelerometer, gyroscope, and barometer. 
so far I have estimate orientation using accelerometer and gyroscope. 
now I want to combine the data from accelerometer and gyroscope with the barometer to find the vertical height.

so far I have estimate orientation using accelerometer and gyroscope. 
now I want to combine the data from accelerometer and gyroscope with the barometer to find the vertical height.

```
 phi_hat_gyr(i)   = phi_hat   + dt * (p + sin(phi_hat) * tan(theta_hat) * q + cos(phi_hat) * tan(theta_hat) * r);
   theta_hat_gyr(i) = theta_hat + dt * (cos(phi_hat) * q - sin(phi_hat) * r);
```

the result should in the form of vertical height.

thanks!

Comment: please any one can help me out in above mentioned problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think a [Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) is quite suited to your task. The best simple explanation i know of can be found [here](https://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/). It will give you temporal filtering as well as sensor fusion.

The difficult part is setting up the transition/measurement matrices. Since your problem is non-linear you will have to use the extended Kalman Filter, which uses different transition/measurement matrices as the state changes.